# Confirm with user before updating bound property change if dirty

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a drop down box that will change what is displayed on the screen. If the IsDirty variable is true I want a popup to notify the user that an unsaved change exists if they try to change the drop down.

The drop down is bound to the property and my attempts to just put the message box into the set of the property did not work well. It seems every time I try to intercept the chance and modify it the result is the set on the property fires again.

I have tried a few solutions I found online with no luck, anyone have any sugestions?

My latest try is attaching a behavior, but it has the same problems of firing multiple times and the values has changed anyway.

I am using .net 4.5

```
 public class CancellableSelectionBehavior : Behavior<ComboBox>
    {

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    #region Properties

    #region IsDirtyCheck

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDirtyCheckProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            Reflection.GetPropertyName<CancellableSelectionBehavior>(m => m.IsDirtyCheck),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(CancellableSelectionBehavior));

    public bool IsDirtyCheck
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsDirtyCheckProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsDirtyCheckProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Selected Value

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(Reflection.GetPropertyName<CancellableSelectionBehavior>(m => m.SelectedValue),
                                    typeof(object), typeof(CancellableSelectionBehavior),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                                                                  FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions
                                                                      .BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnSelectedItemChanged));

    public object SelectedValue
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion

    private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var behavior = (CancellableSelectionBehavior)d;
        var selector = behavior.AssociatedObject;

        if (e.OldValue != null)
        {
            if (e.OldValue != e.NewValue)
            {
                if (behavior.IsDirtyCheck)
                {
                    string message = string.Format(UserMessages.UnSavedFaultPlygon, Environment.NewLine);
                    if (ServiceLocationContext.ServiceFinder.GetService<IMessageBox>()
                                              .Show(new MessageDialogOptions(message,
                                                                             UserMessages
                                                                                 .FaultPlygons,
                                                                             MessageDialogIcon
                                                                                 .Exclamation,
                                                                             MessageDialogButtons
                                                                                 .YesNo)) == MessageDialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        selector.SelectedValue = e.NewValue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        selector.SelectedValue = e.OldValue;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    selector.SelectedValue = e.NewValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the associated selector's selection is changed.
    /// Tries to assign it to the <see cref="SelectedItem"/> property.
    /// If it fails, updates the selector's with  <see cref="SelectedItem"/> property's current value.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.AddedItems == null || e.AddedItems.Count == 0)) return;
        SelectedValue = AssociatedObject.SelectedValue;
    }

}





<ribbonDropDown:RibbonDropDownListView
                            Label="{Binding Path=MapModel.SelectedPostingItemName}"
                            Image="{Binding Path=LargeImageSource, ElementName=_postingTypeMenuButton}" 
                            Width="100"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MapModel.PostingHorizonItems}"                            
                            SelectedValuePath="Key"
                            Visibility="{Binding Path=MapModel.SelectedTypeKey, Converter={StaticResource EnumMatchToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static map2:MapPostingType.Horizon}}"
                            ToolTip="{Binding Path=MapModel.SelectedPostingItemDescription}">
                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <common:CancellableSelectionBehavior IsDirtyCheck="{Binding Path=MapControlViewModel.IsFaultPolygonDirty}"
                                                                     SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MapModel.SelectedHorizonPostingItem}"/>
                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be way oversimplifying the answer but I believe the issue is you are capturing the onselectionchanged event and then changing the selection inside of that code block.

The behavior is neat seeming but I think you have to hook it up not based on this kind of event.

I would solve the problem like this.  (Maybe having a try with a finally to reattach the event if you think you might throw an exception.)

```
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    if ((e.AddedItems == null || e.AddedItems.Count == 0)) return;
    AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
    SelectedValue = AssociatedObject.SelectedValue;
    AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, It seems this has the same issues as the majority of things I have tried. It will ask twice to confirm if you want to continue, and it will also trigger the property change and clear any changes before asking if it should continue.